# Avoid Matlab Loop for adding value

Tags: matlab

I would like to avoid the for loop in my code, since that is so pretty computationally intensive.

I search my data frame for a variable, if the variable is 0 the amount 1000 should be added to another variable.
The same if the variable is 1.

```
for i=1:height(dataframe)
if df.status(i) ==0
    df.Number(i) = df.Number(i)+10000;
else if df.status(i) ==1
        df.Number(i) = df.Number(i)+20000;
    end
end
end
```

I am very grateful for any advice-
Tim

Comment: If `status` is a boolean, you can do something like `df.Number += 10000; df.Number(df.status == 1) += 10000`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your loop visits each element in `df.Number` and `df.status` is also the same size, then you can summarize your code as

```matlab
df.Number = df.Number + 10000 + (df.status==1) * 10000;
```

A logical value (Boolean) in MATLAB always has the value of either 0 or 1, and comparing `status==1` ensures a logical value.

If `df.status` is a logical, you can skip the comparison: `10000 + df.status * 10000`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the data type of the data frame but you can approach this by getting the index when that condition is reached.

```
% Generate a simple dataframe
dataframe = [0 0 1 1 2 2 1 0 5]';

% Get 0s index and add 10,000 to those indexes
idx_0 = dataframe == 0;
dataframe(idx_0) = dataframe(idx_0) + 10000;
% Get 1s index and add 20,000 to those indexes
idx_1 = dataframe == 1;
dataframe(idx_1) = dataframe(idx_1) + 20000; 
  
% Print dataframe variable
dataframe
```